# Como centralizar o label do eixo y no ggiraphExtra::ggRadar()?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Procuro uma forma de centralizar o `label` do eixo y em um gráfico do tipo spider-web. Estou utilizando o pacote `ggiraphExtra` e a função `ggRadar`. Porém, o label fica externo no lado esquedo, e eu gostaria de colocá-lo centralizado dentro do gráfico, em cada linha de grade.

Exemplo de código:

```r
library(ggiraphExtra)
ggRadar(data=iris, aes(group=Species))
```

[image: Grafico apresentado o label do eixo y externo, e fora do gráfico, desalinhado da grade]

O que eu gostaria é que ficasse parecido com o exemplo 2 abaixo, utilizando o pacote `fmsb` com a função `radarchart`. O problema dessa função que eu não consigo linkar funções do pacote `ggplot2` nela, havendo a necessidade de ter que concaternar gráficos. Além disso, o gráfico gerado possui resolução pequena.

Código do exemplo 2:

```
library(fmsb)

radarchart(
    rbind(
    data.frame(group=c("min","max"), Thickness=c(0,10), Apperance=c(0,10), Spredability=c(0,10), Likeability=c(0,10)),
    data)[,c(2:5)],seg = 5,
    caxislabels=seq(0,10,2),
    axislabcol="black",
    axistype=1)
```

[image: Exemplo 2, com os labels centralizado]

O gráfico está feio, mas da pra se ter uma idéia do que preciso.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se você precisa obrigatoriamente usar o pacote `ggiraphExtra`. Caso não precise, aqui vai uma alternativa usando `ggradar::ggradar`.

```
library(scales)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggradar)

iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(petal_width = mean(Petal.Width),
            sepal_length = mean(Sepal.Length),
            septal_width = mean(Sepal.Width),
            petal_length = mean(Petal.Length)) %>% 
   mutate_at(vars(-Species), funs(rescale)) %>% 
   ggradar(group.point.size = 0.3,
           axis.label.offset = 1.2)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Infelizmente essa função me atende, pois limita a 3 grids apenas!